# Node MySQL hanging

Tags: mysql, node.js, get, database-connection

I have my GET endpoint which is just a simple SELECT * FROM tableName and returns all the rows in the table but it keeps hanging. When I hit it in POSTMAN locally it just keep spinning with

Sending request... and the program never errors.
The get endpoint is hanging after connection.query(...) and the fourth console.log("HIT) is not printed

```
router.get('/allRows', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("HIT")
    if (req.query.tableName) {
        console.log("HIT")
        connection.connect((err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            console.log("HIT")
            connection.query(`SELECT * FROM ${req.query.tableName};`), (err, result, fields) => {
                console.log("HIT")
                if (err) console.log(err);
                console.log(result)
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: `Successfully got all data from ${req.query.tableName}`,
                    result: result
                });
            };
            connection.end((err) => {
                if (err)
                    console.error("Error when closing connection", err)
            });
        })
    }
    else {
        res.status(400).json({
            message: `Please provide table name`,
        });
        console.log('Missing table name');
    }
});
```

I have 3 "HIT" logs at the moment, any ideas?

I noticed that if I cancel the endless request in postman and I hit the endpoint again I get a **PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT** error

**EDIT**

I changed my code to this:

```
    router.get('/allRows', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("HIT")
    // also another guard for table name inside an array is needed
    if (req.query.tableName) {
            console.log("HIT")
            connection.connect();
            connection.query(`SELECT * FROM ${req.query.tableName}`), (err, rows, fields) => {
                console.log("HIT", rows)
                if (err) console.log(err);
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: `Successfully got all data from ${req.query.tableName} LIMIT 1`,
                    result: rows
                });
                console.log("result")
            };
    }
    else {
        res.status(400).json({
            message: `Please provide table name`,
        });
        console.log('Missing table name');
    }
});
```

Still get the same issue and only 2 console hits... I have ran the debugger and when it gets to connection.query it just skips over it and doesn't go into the arrow function.

[debugger at connection.query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr9FE.jpg)

[debugger after connection.query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUVSZ.jpg)

Comment: Side note: It's really bad practice to let the table name be an outside query parameter.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I could just escape it with mysql.escape()? It is a private API just for my use only - do you think this would be ok or can you suggest anything better? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: use a white list for valid table names

Comment: I think the problem is connection.connect, any doc for this?

Comment: I am using this NPM mopdule https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Comment: @nbk You mean whitelist check against req.query.tableName?

Comment: I notice this part `connection.query(\`SELECT * FROM ${req.query.tableName};\`), (err, result, fields) => {` ..and felt strange about it.. normally I see something like this `connection.query(\`SELECT * FROM ${req.query.tableName};\` , (err, result, fields) => {` .. the closing bracket [`)`] right after the query seems like misplaced. It should be added at the `}); };` >>> ` `}); });`

Comment: @user2921885 yes that is the only secure way, everything that doesn't exist in the array gets blocked

Comment: I updated answer with some more info as this is still unresolved please check

Answer (score 0):

According to module docs, connection.connect is going to build live linking to database.

Just call it at server startup, and stop it when sever down.

Call connection.query when you want to solve requests.

```js
connection.connect()

router.get(
   .....

  connection.query()
)

server.on(‘close’, ()=> connection.close()) // I guess
```

with connect error:

```
connection.connect(function(err) {
  console.log(err.code); // 'ECONNREFUSED'
  console.log(err.fatal); // true
});
router.get(
   .....

  connection.query()
)

server.on(‘close’, ()=> connection.close()) // I guess
```

Comment: what msg you got?

Comment: did you see where i call connect()? outside